# How calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{n+\frac{1}{n}}}{(n+\frac{1}{n})^n}$

Tags: calculus

Give a hit to calculate this limit. $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{n+\frac{1}{n}}}{(n+\frac{1}{n})^n}$$

Comment: Note that $n^{1/n}$ tends to $1$ and hence the expression under limit can be replaced by $1/(1+n^{-2})^{n}$ which tends to $1$ via Bernoulli's inequality.

Answer (score 4):

Divide numerator and denominator by $n^n$. Then you can evaluate the limits of numerator and denominator separately, do you see how?